# Typeerror at /blog/: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'QuerySet'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

**I am Trying To Create A Basic Blog Website with multiple urls working in django.**

For the Blog Page I have created a Custom template tag which will return the first few words from the content data of blog from Models.
But when i am trying to execute it always displaying the same error
*'expected string or bytes-like object, got 'QuerySet'*

**This Is My :Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class blogdata(models.Model):
    post_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
    heading=models.CharField(max_length=500 ,default="")
    content=models.CharField(max_length=900 ,default="",null=True)
    date=models.DateField()
    thumbnail=models.ImageField(upload_to='static/',default="")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**This is my post_tags.py**

```
import re
from django import template
from ..models import blogdata 

register=template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def FewFirst():
    my_str=blogdata.objects.values_list('content')
    result = re.findall(r'\w+', my_str)[:10 ]
    result = " ".join(result)
    return result
```

*Note: Directory structure and file names are correct idk the main reason behind this error*

Comment: Post your view function and also the HTML where you have used this filter

Comment: Use `BlogData` instead of blogdata for class name: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0):

This line: `my_str=blogdata.objects.values_list('content')`

Should be: `my_str=blogdata.objects.values_list('content', flat=True).first()`

See more at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/